# How do you call a function once a dijit dialog is done loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, dialog

I'm using a dijit dialog that uses a url to populate its content with a partial view. However, I have to call a function that uses the content of this dialog.

The function requires a value of an input from this dialog, but gets called too early since the dialog takes some time to completely load its entire content to the DOM.

I can't find any onLoad events online for dijit dialogs, and currently I'm using setTimeout for this as a work around, but this isn't an elegant solution, since the server may be slow one day for some reasons, and then the function may get called earlier than the dialog getting loaded.

How can I call my function exactly after the dialog have been loaded to the DOM?

Comment: According to the [dijit Dialog reference](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/#1_10dijit_Dialog_onLoad), there is an 'onLoad' event?

Comment: From my experience I find that onDownloadEnd is a more reliable event than onLoad when loading a contentPane from a url